# PatternLayout not substituting values from ThreadContext in Java

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, pattern-layout

I am tying to create a PatternLayout object in Java code that will have its values substituted from the ThreadContext, using the `%X` (and %d) placeholder.

```
private PatternLayout patternLayout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                                                   .withPattern("op1=%X{op1}|op2=%X{op2}|timestamp=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}")
                                                   .build();
```

I have also implemented the Log4J `Message` interface:

```
private final PatternLayout pattern;

MyLoggingMessage(final PatternLayout pattern) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedMessage() {

    // I have also tried return pattern.getContentFormat();
    return pattern.toString();
}
```

However, when this is recorded in Graylog, the values have not been substituted out, and remains `op1=%X{op1}|op2=%X{op2}|timestamp=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}`.  However, if I use an XML implementation of the same pattern in my appender,...

```
<PatternLayout pattern="op1=%X{op1}|op2=%X{op2}|timestamp=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}" />
```

it all gets substituted out.  How can I get log4j to evaluate the pattern in Java?  From what I can see, both methods just set the `pattern` field.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `pattern.format(LoggingEvent)` somewhere instead of just `pattern.toString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked for me:

```
private final StringMap params;

MyLoggingMessage(final PatternLayout pattern) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.params = (StringMap) ThreadContext.getContext();
}

@Override
public String getFormattedMessage() {

    LogEvent logEvent = Log4jLogEvent.newBuilder()
                                     .setContextData(params)
                                     .build();

    return pattern.toSerializable(logEvent);
}
```